# Change the file name in log4j rolling appender

Tags: java, apache, logging

How to change the file names in rolling file appender after the file is reached its max limit,currently it is displaying the names

```
myStruts1App.log
myStruts1App.log.1
myStruts1App.log.2
```

I need the files name as

```
myStrutsApp1.log
myStrutsApp2.log
```

Sample Code

```
<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
<param name="append" value="false" />
<param name="maxFileSize" value="10KB" />
<param name="maxBackupIndex" value="5" />
<param name="file" value="${catalina.home}/logs/myStruts1App.log" />
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} 
%-5p  %c{1}:%L - %m%n />
</layout>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below. I added `-%i` to file name. That should do the increment part of it. Let me know if it works.

```
<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
<param name="append" value="false" />
<param name="maxFileSize" value="10KB" />
<param name="maxBackupIndex" value="5" />
<param name="file" value="${catalina.home}/logs/myStruts1App-%i.log" />
<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} 
%-5p  %c{1}:%L - %m%n />
</layout>
</appender>
```

1.X version does not support it. Here is the code of the logic. Try extending the RollingFileAppender and override  rollOver() method. It should be straight forward to do it.

```
 for (int i = maxBackupIndex - 1; i >= 1 && renameSucceeded; i--) {
file = new File(fileName + "." + i);
if (file.exists()) {
  target = new File(fileName + '.' + (i + 1));
  LogLog.debug("Renaming file " + file + " to " + target);
  renameSucceeded = file.renameTo(target);
}
  }
```

Comment: no giving correct output ,file name is   myStruts1App-%i.log.1

Comment: Yes. That was for log4j2.x... missed to add that information. I have not tried that in 1.x version.

Comment: can u please provide for 1.x

Comment: Unfortunately, 1.x version does not do that, based on analysis of the code. You can extend  RollingFileAppender and use it. I added the code in my answer, where the renaming while roll over happens. Hope his helps.